# NSView doesn't show update

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I'm trying to to programmatically update a view. Therefore I have a controller and a view. The controller should update the view on a button press. But although the methods get called the view isn't visibly updated.

I found out that the `NSView` has another object ID than the controller is retaining. (Is that the right term?)

This is the code:

```
//  myView.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface myView : NSView

{
    int numberToDisplay;

}



-(void)seedNumber;
-(int)numberToDisplay;

@end

--------------------------------------------------------

//  myView.m

#import "myView.h"

@implementation myView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"View loaded\n%@",self);
        numberToDisplay = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSLog(@"view is drawing");
    //Draw
    NSRect textRect = NSMakeRect(5, 5, 100, 100);
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
    textStyle.alignment = NSCenterTextAlignment;

    NSDictionary* textFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [NSFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 50], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.blackColor, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle};

    [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",numberToDisplay] drawInRect: NSOffsetRect(textRect, 0, 1) withAttributes: textFontAttributes];
}


-(void)seedNumber;
{
    numberToDisplay++;
    NSLog(@"view:%d",numberToDisplay);
}
-(int)numberToDisplay
{
    return numberToDisplay;
}
@end
--------------------------------------------------------

//  controller.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class myView;

@interface controller : NSObject

{
    myView *view;
}


-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end

--------------------------------------------------------
//  controller.m

#import "controller.h"
#import "myView.h"

@implementation controller

-(void)awakeFromNib
{

    view = [[myView alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"controller loaded\n%@",view);
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [view seedNumber];
    NSLog(@"controller: %d",[view numberToDisplay]);
    [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
@end
--------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is what command line is returning ( when the button is pressed ):

```
2014-05-26 11:58:20.036 graphikTest[1230:303] View loaded
<myView: 0x60000012e7e0>
2014-05-26 11:58:20.049 graphikTest[1230:303] View loaded
<myView: 0x60800012f140>
2014-05-26 11:58:20.049 graphikTest[1230:303] controller loaded
<myView: 0x60800012f140>
2014-05-26 11:58:20.087 graphikTest[1230:303] view is drawing
2014-05-26 11:58:22.083 graphikTest[1230:303] view:1
2014-05-26 11:58:22.083 graphikTest[1230:303] controller: 1
2014-05-26 11:58:22.982 graphikTest[1230:303] view:2
2014-05-26 11:58:22.983 graphikTest[1230:303] controller: 2
2014-05-26 11:58:23.432 graphikTest[1230:303] view:3
2014-05-26 11:58:23.433 graphikTest[1230:303] controller: 3
2014-05-26 11:58:23.635 graphikTest[1230:303] view:4
2014-05-26 11:58:23.636 graphikTest[1230:303] controller: 4
2014-05-26 11:58:23.849 graphikTest[1230:303] view:5
2014-05-26 11:58:23.850 graphikTest[1230:303] controller: 5
```

...
So it should actually work-I can't find out why it's not redrawing.
Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please edit [your existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858211/objective-c-seems-to-send-to-the-wrong-object) rather than reposting.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! You are going about this the hard way.

If the NSView which is displayed does not have the same address (you called it object ID) as the NSView instance retained by the controller instance, then you have two instances of NSView. One which is being displayed and another undisplayed view which is being handled by the controller instance. This happened because when you allocated the controller, you allocated another instance of myView during awakeFromNib:. This instance is distinct from the instance of myView which appears in your nib. If you want to do it this way, then declare controler-view as an IBOutlet and connect it in your nib (then remove the awakeFromNib method entirely).

Also: You can ditch the controller instance completely and move -buttonPressed: to myView then connect the action in the nib file like you did before to the first responder instead.

Also: You can use an instance of NSTextField to display the number and set the intValue property of the NSTextField (self) in -buttonPressed: which will cause the value to be displayed as text automatically. You can set the font, etc. in the interface builder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - and you're right, I could put it in the view and I also could use a textField which I change - but my problem is, I have to pass data to NSView and it doesn't work - this is the MAIN issue. If I don't allocate the view on awakeFromNib I don't get any data passed to the view.